# How algebraic (or more general) expression is represented (memory level, data structure) in Mathematica?

Tags: symbolic, algorithm, implementation-details, free-wolfram-engine

This is not a question about the usage of Mathematica, it is more about implementation. Mathematica is a very huge system, it can provide a series of very advanced operation against a Mathematica expression.

The engine of Mathematica is implemented with C or C++ not Python. Since it is implemented by native language, how the expression is represented in C/Memory aspect?

And how Mathematica organize its massively amount of expression manipulation algorithm. Is it organized in a Object-Oriented way like Sympy? or some other ways else?

Is there anyone who can make a general introduction about the structure of Mathematica, not focusing on any single algorithm or expression, just the broad, general view?

Comment: If you haven't already, have a look at https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html and see where it leads you.